# One IValueConverter for all properties set in style

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to set a IValueConverter for a textbox when styling it?

The converter are used to hide zeros and showing placeholder values for empty values.

I would like to use the converter without knowing the name of the property of the bound object, so all bindings are using my converter, Can I do it?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,6"/>
   <Setter Property="Text">
       <Setter.Value>
           <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Converter="{textBoxTest:FormatIntAndDoubleValueConverter}"/>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
       </Trigger>
       <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: To start, the converter is missing the {StaticResource textBoxTest:FormatIntAndDoubleValueConverter}

Comment: The converter binding is working I am using this code as a [baseclass](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) 'public class BaseConverter : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }'